# What is the easiest way to transfer changes from one server to another without recreating tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a test and a development server. What is the easiest way to get the changes of the table from the development server to the test server without losing data (Drop Table... Create Table...)?

Comment: updated my response with a link to a free (but severely limited) compare tool

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to come up with a solid release management process.

Let your developers write release and rollback scripts for each change they make.
Insist on SQL scripts instead of GUI based changes.(use the GUI to write your scripts - nothing wrong with that)

By doing so, when the code is completed, you have the code prepared for migration from Development to Test, and then use the same scripts to move from Test to Production.

By doing this you can

1. Restore Production Database into Test environment and test your release & rollback.
2. Restore Production Database into Development Environment and be able to get back to where you were in your development life-cycle. (This is sometimes useful if you need to test with "fresh" data)

I tend to user the following folder structure

```
ChangeNo-xxxxx-Description
--> release.bat (sqlcmd script to loop through release folder)
--> rollback.bat (sqlcmd script to loop through rollback folder)
--> release (folder)
---->0001.ChangeDescription.sql
---->0002.ChangeDescription.sql
--> rollback (folder)
---->0001.ChangeDescription.sql
---->0002.ChangeDescription.sql
```

Also to test my release process rapidly, I tend to take database snapshots. Test a release. Revert to snapshot if necessary and try again.

The easiest way to synchronize your schemas between environments is to use Red-Gate SQL Compare or Embarcadero DB Change Manager, however once the schema is synchronized will you have any idea of why you made any change or a method of reversing any of the changes. made ?

Both are excellent tools, however it seems you may want to establish a controlled change process in your environment.

Great tool are not a substitute for change and release management.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  The snapshot is pure genius and really helps with large databases.

Answer (score 2):

Stefan, you have asked several times if there are free tools and the answer is still the same, no.  The companies who are taking the time and investing to develop a quality product cannot give it away.

If you want something which you already own you could perform these steps

1. Script both databases
2. Inspect the two files in Notepad for any difference

I agree with John that you should develop a repeatable process to upgrade any target db to your current "GOLD" schema because that is what you will be doing at your customer's site.  You will save money in the long run if you will spend some money now and hire someine who has a proven track record in running a development department.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like Red-Gate [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

Or if you have SQL Server **Express** editions, you could use the free [xSQL Lite Edition](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/LiteEdition.aspx) which are limited to a maximum number of tables and other database objects - but hey, it's FREE! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to "vote up" John DaCosta's answer--but, alas, I don't have enough of a reputation on Stack Overflow to be able to do so.

But he's correct--entirely correct. I use RedGate's SQL tools and highly recommend them; but I also concur with John's excellent point that all the nifty tools in the world are no substitute for a carefully-defined release process.

So while I can't "vote up" John's post--I at least lift my coffee cup in his direction. (Wherever he is.)

Answer (score 0):

RedGate has a bundle of tools which can sync the database structure and data.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/

Answer (score 0):

All data base changes should be scripted (changes to tables should be alter table not drop and create if you want to preserve data) and put into source control. Then changes that go with a particular release are in the folder for that release. There is no good substitute for doing this and changes to the database should be treated as code changes just like all other code. Using a tool to do comparisions is generally a poor way to go becasue it doesn't know which chnages belong in the particular release and which are not yet ready to be moved to another server. Only the developers know this and thus they are responsible for ensuring all things which go with a release are in source control marked for that release. An automated tool won't fix your developers incompetence, it may in fact make things worse when thigns are promoted to prod that should not be.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other contributors that a solid release process should be in order, but if you're just looking for a quick solution to your problem, you can do the following:

1. Perform a backup of the destination database (VERY IMPORTANT).
2. On the development (source) database, script the DROP & CREATE of the new table via SQL Management Studio by right clicking the table Script Table as | DROP and CREATE to | New Query Editor window.  Make sure that the script includes any Indexes and default values, etc that you want to preserve. DON'T EXECUTE THIS SCRIPT YET.
3. On the test (destination) database, execute the following SQL:

> ```
> SELECT
>     *
> INTO
>     MyTable_temp
> FROM
>     MyTable
> ```

1. Execute the DROP and CREATE script from step 1 on the DESTINATION database.
2. On the destination database, execute the following SQL (replace the table and field names with the appropriate values):

> ```
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON
> GO
>
> INSERT INTO
>     MyTable
> (
>     Field1
> ,   Field2
> ,   Field3
> ,   Field4
> ,   ...
> )
> SELECT
> (
>     Field1
> ,   Field2
> ,   Field3
> ,   Field4
> ,   ...
> )
> FROM
>     MyTable_temp
>
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
> GO
> ```

1. Confirm that everything is there by performing a

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
> ```

1. If everything looks OK, then DROP the temp table

> ```
> DROP TABLE MyTable_temp
> ```